# SNMP Returned value

Tags: php, linux, performance

I want to code some performance indicators and I have this output from my server when issuing `snmpget` command but I don't know how to convert 15444916248593342 and 124677611671696419 into bits.

```
snmpget -v 2c -c comm 1.2.2.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.661
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.661 = Counter64: 15444916248593342        
snmpget -v 2c -c comm 1.2.2.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10.661
iso.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10.661 = Counter64: 124677611671696419
```

I tried several methods by without any success.

Comment: what does it have to do with php?

Comment: I want to use snmpget from php script to retrive used bandwidth on our router interfaces.

Comment: I want to use snmpget into php script to retrieve our router interface usage in real time.